# NodeValue in XML not getting updated with XPATH DOM

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying  same approach to  update the node value but XML is  never getting updated.  I  don't get any errors also.
Have tried almost all options:(Need help!!!

```
$queryResult = $xpath->query("//USER[@EMAIL_ID='$dbEmail']");

 foreach($queryResult as $result)
 {
     foreach ($result->getElementsByTagName('NAME') as $tempName) {
          $tempName->nodeValue = "changed";                                
 }


}
```

Comment: can you post [minimal codes to reproduce the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/2998271)?